# HTTP 'auth_basic' Error on NGINX

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

My code to secure the wp-login page is throwing an error:
`nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "auth_basic" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/wordpress.conf:41`

I am not sure what is wrong within the auth_basic directive.

The following is the code located within the server block on NGINX 1.17.10

`location /wp-login.php$ { auth_basic “Administrator’s Area”; auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd; }`

apache2-utils has been installed and the user and password has been created for the same too.

Comment: Correct the quotes in `“Administrator’s Area”` to straight ones? `"Administrator’s Area"`

Comment: Worked! But, it still won't show the authentication popup. Not sure what is incorrect here

Comment: Those bad quotes happen when you copy from the nginx docs

Comment: Hmm, they should really fix their docs to be compatible with the software itself...

Answer (score 10):

Using the comments answered this question for me - from @danila-vershinin:

> Correct the quotes in “Administrator’s Area” to straight ones? "Administrator’s Area"

and @jason-prawn:

> Those bad quotes happen when you copy from the nginx docs

(I did exactly that, [link to the nginx docs I was using](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/))